# How to get coverage for Jest toThrow without failing test

Tags: testing, jestjs, code-coverage, enzyme, throw

Let's say I'm testing the below React component with `jest --coverage`:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    if (props.invalid) {
      throw new Error('invalid')
    }
  }
}
```

the coverage report will say that the line `throw new Error('invalid')` is uncovered. Since `.not.toThrow()` doesn't seem to cover anything I create the below test with Enzyme:

```
const wrapper = shallow(
  <MyComponent invalid />
)

it('should throw', () => {
  function fn() {
    if (wrapper.instance().props.invalid) {
      throw new Error('invalid')
    }
  }
  expect(fn).toThrow()
})
```

and the line gets covered! However the test itself fails with `encountered a declaration exception` - meaning the original component threw the error (as it should)?

Am I using [`toThrow()`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tothrowerror) wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `expect(fn()).toThrow()`

Comment: @AndreasKöberle [no](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tothrowerror)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Realise this is an old question, but for future viewers, I thought I'd expand on @galki's answer. Rather than using a try/catch, you could simply wrap your `shallow`/`mount` in an anonymous function and then use `.toThrowError()` instead:

```
const TestComponent = () => {
    throw new Error('Test error');
}

describe('Test Component', () => {
    it('Throws an error', () => {
        expect(() => shallow(<TestComponent />)).toThrowError();
    });
});
```

This gives you much cleaner code, with the same result.

Comment: this also works with Stateless: `expect(() => shallow(TestComponent())).toThrowError();`

Answer (score 5):

Apparently this is connected to [how React 16 handles errors](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html). I managed to get the test passing by wrapping `MyComponent` with a parent React component that has a `componentDidCatch` method.

This made the test pass but to affect the coverage, I had to change `shallow` to `mount`. The test ended up looking like this:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidCatch(error) {
    // console.log(error)
  }
  render() {
    return this.props.children
  }
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    if (props.invalid) {
      throw new Error('invalid')
    }
  }
}

const wrapper = mount(
  <ParentComponent>
    <MyComponent invalid />
  </ParentComponent>
)

it('should throw', () => {
  function fn() {
    if (wrapper.props().invalid) {
      throw new Error('invalid test')
    }
  }
  expect(fn).toThrow()
})
```

**UPDATE**

After realizing that the problem was an error being thrown inside `shallow` or `mount` (before it got to the test), I simplified the whole thing to this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    if (props.invalid) {
      throw new Error('invalid')
    }
  }
}

it('should throw', () => {
  let error
  try {
    shallow(<MyComponent invalid />)
  } catch (e) {
    error = e
  }
  expect(error).toBeInstanceOf(Error)
})
```

Comment: wow you saved me, that is correct. `.toThrow()`only works on pure functions, if we use renderer or shallow, this test does not work.

Comment: Rather than having to use a `let` and assign the result of the try/catch, why not just wrap the `shallow()` in an anonymous function and call `.toThrowError()` on it? E.g. `expect(() => shallow(<TestComponent />)).toThrowError();`

Answer (score 0):

galki, I think the problem is that you throw error while *constructuring* component. And it fails test, as it should (you're totally right).
Instead, if you can extract prop-checking function somewhere else, where it will not be called during mounting - it will work perfectly. For example, I modified your snippets as

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.invalid) {
      throw new Error('invalid')
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div/>
    )
  }
}
```

and

```
const wrapper = shallow(
 <MyComponent />
)

it('should throw', () => {
  function fn() {
    wrapper.setProps({invalid: true});
  };
  expect(fn).toThrow();
})
```

So, if you have a chance to not throw an error while mounting - you will be able to test it.

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is not called in this case. id like to test on component creation, not on update