# How to make enzyme expect error after re-render of component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I want to do something similar as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54236161/1479895) to another question

Imagine I have a test like this

```
const TestComponent = () => {
   if (someCondition) {
    throw new Error('Test error');
   } else { 
    return <div> bla </div>
   }
}

describe('Test Component', () => {
    it('Throws an error', () => {
        let component = shallow(<TestComponent />);

        // do some setup which will cause the component to re-render
        // and go through the someCondition branch

        try {
          component.update();
        }catch(err) {
          // assert the error here
        }

        // here I want to somehow assert that the component has thrown an exception during the re-render
    });
});
```

Currently my code is not reaching the catch clause and the whole test case fails with the error thrown from the `TestComponent` I'm not sure why the catch is not catching that. What is the proper way to assert that a re-rendered component has thrown an exception and do some `expect` on the actual exception?

Comment: just move `shallow(...)` inside of `try { ... } ` block

Answer (score 0):

I ended up triggering the re-render of the Component under test manually using `component.instance().render()`

```
class TestComponent extends Component {

   // some other things

   render() {
     if (this.state.someCondition) {
      throw new Error('Test error');
     } else { 
      return <div> bla </div>
     }
   }
}

describe('Test Component', () => {
    it('Throws an error', () => {
        let component = shallow(<TestComponent />);

        // some code which triggers a setState in the TestComponent that
        // will set the `someCondition` to true, thus triggering re-render, that will throw error

        let caughtErrorsCount = 0;
        try {
          component.instance().render();
        }catch(err) {
          // assert the error here
          expect(err).toEqual(expectedError);
          caughtErrorsCount += 1;
        }

        expect(caughtErrorsCount).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

As described in [the toThrowError documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tothrowerror)

> You must wrap the code in a function, otherwise the error will not be caught and the assertion will fail.

so you can:

```
describe('Test Componnet', () => {
  it('should throw error', () => {
    expect(() => shallow(<TestComponent />)).toThrowError();
  }
}
```

in your code **"the catch is not catching"**, because the error is being thrown from the `shallow` execution and the try-catch block is not being executed.

Take a look at [this working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/render-error-testing-tkx93)

Comment: But the problem is that between the first time i call `shallow` and then `component.update()` there is some code which will change the state of the component and trigger re-render, and the second re-render is the one I'm expecting to throw the error.

Comment: Can confirm, using this approach on a component that does not throw an error on the initial render will result in jest saying `Received function did not throw`. The assertion does not cover a re-render.